# Returned URL as String is not valid in JSF

Tags: java, string, jsf-2, icefaces

I'm trying to make use of google api as text-to-speech. So, I build a String then should pass it as a URL to a component to obtain a MP3 with the spoken words.
So, this is my code:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=es&q="+ URLEncoder.encode((String)this.text.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
```

When I make `uri.toString()` its return a well formed URL. If I copy and paste this output in the browser works pefectly.
But if I assign this returned String to the source property of a ice:outputMedia is not working. Then inspect the HTML generated in the page and the String in src property is:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=es&amp;q=Bobby+need+peanuts
```

The & symbol has been replaced by `&amp;`.

How can I avoid this to make a valid URL?

Comment: +1 for the google text-to-speech tip!

Comment: Thanks! Give it a try! It works excellent! If you can build the URL string correctly of course, je

Answer (score 0):

You need to [decode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) the url on the client side using Javascript.

```
var decoded = decodeURI(URI)
```

Comment: How can I decode a String that is returned from a managed bean and then put it in the source of the component? Any idea?

Comment: Java URIDecoder http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#URLDecoder%28%29

Comment: If I use this method in the string before return it, nothing happen, the String in the page when I see the code is still with `&amp;`instead of &